# Add variable value in payload string in Python

Tags: python, string, variables

I have payload string that i want to modify in a loop but i can not figure out how to convert this '41.86464600000019' and this '-87.80732699999984' in variables to replace them in a loop. inserting f{} did not help

here is the full string

```
  payload = "{\"showPrice\":\"DISCOUNT\",\"searchRange\":80.467,\"points\":[{\"latitude\":41.86464600000019,\"longitude\":-87.80732699999984}],\"cardNumber\":\"blablabla\",\"_mt926720371\":\"3796524828557652229\"}"
```

Comment: The syntax is : a=1234 ; st=f"bonjour {a}" ; st -> Out[230]: 'bonjour 1234' ; thus, for you :  payload = f"....... {LATITUDE} ......." .

Comment: What did you try exactly? Please make a [mre]. For more tips, like how to write a good title, please read [ask]. If you don't know how to use f-strings, do a tutorial, for example [the official one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

Answer (score 0):

Quite difficult with strings.
You can switch payload to dict.

```py
payload = {'showPrice': 'DISCOUNT',
 'searchRange': 80.467,
 'points': [{'latitude': 41.86464600000019, 'longitude': -87.80732699999984}],
 'cardNumber': 'blablabla',
 '_mt926720371': '3796524828557652229'}

# a set of two (lat, lon) tuples just for the sake of example
coords = [(41.86464600000019, -87.80732699999984), (41.86464600000020, -87.80732699999985)]

for lat, lon in coords:
    payload["points"] = [{"latitude": lat, "longitude": lon}]
    payload = json.dumps(payload)  # if you need to obtain it as a string
```